# Reactive Extensions Instant Search for WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive

I would like to implement a TextBox where, as you type, results appear instantly in another ListBox. I've been looking for examples with Reactive Extensions (Rx), and all of the ones I found use `Observable.FromEventPattern()` together with the TextBox's `TextChanged` event:

- [Implementing simple instant search with Rx (Reactive Extensions)](http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/implementing-simple-instant-search-with-rx-reactive-extensions#.U1JDnvmSxpm) (this is actually WinForms)
- [An Rx-Enabled WPF AutoComplete TextBox - Part 1/2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/argumentnullexceptionblogpost/archive/2013/06/21/an-rx-enabled-wpf-control-part-1-2.aspx)
- [Search on TextChanged with Reactive Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873541/search-on-textchanged-with-reactive-extensions)

I'm using WPF with MVVM so I can't exactly access the TextBox or its events directly.

*I've also stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4585919/983064) which shows how `Observable.FromEventPattern()` can be used in an MVVM setting, but I was hoping for something better than capturing every single `PropertyChanged` event.*

What is a good alternative to `Observable.FromEventPattern()` that can work nicely with WPF/MVVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working with [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/).

The solution is based on a [blog post](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/05/reactivexaml-series-implementing-search-with-observableaspropertyhelper/) at [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/), but the code there is a little bit [out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170139/reactiveui-5-instant-search). I am hosting the [solution](https://bitbucket.org/dandago/experimental/src/2399934fd50b2b956c345b639a9c15fdf5d3c3de/ReactiveExtensionsSearch/?at=master) on BitBucket for ease of access. It uses ReactiveUI 5.5.1.

This is the ViewModel from that solution. `SearchText` is bound to a `TextBox` in the View where the user types his query, while `SearchResults` is bound to a `ListBox` displaying the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Windows.Input;

using ReactiveUI;

namespace ReactiveExtensionsSearch
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private string[] _repository = new string[]
            { "Mario", "Maria", "Gigi", "Jack", "James", "Jeremy" };
        private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ObservableCollection<string>> _searchResults;
        private string _searchText;
        private ICommand _executeSearchCommand;

        public string SearchText
        {
            get
            {
                return _searchText;
            }
            set
            {
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _searchText, value);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> SearchResults
        {
            get
            {
                return _searchResults.Value;
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            var executeSearchCommand = new ReactiveCommand();
            var results = executeSearchCommand.RegisterAsyncFunction(s => { return ExecuteSearch(s as string); });
            _executeSearchCommand = executeSearchCommand;

            this.ObservableForProperty<MainWindowViewModel, string>("SearchText")
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .Subscribe(_executeSearchCommand.Execute);

           _searchResults = new ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ObservableCollection<string>>(results, _ => raisePropertyChanged("SearchResults"));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> ExecuteSearch(string searchText)
        {
            var q = from s in _repository where s.ToLower().StartsWith(searchText.ToLower()) select s;
            var results = new ObservableCollection<string>(q);
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of approach that I would use in this instance:

```
        var query = Observable.FromEventPattern
            <TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
                h => textBox1.TextChanged += h,
                h => textBox1.TextChanged -= h)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Select(x => textBox1.Text)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Do(x => listBox1.Items.Clear())
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Select(x => executeSearch(x))
            .Switch()
            .ObserveOnDispatcher();

        query.Subscribe(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
```

The `executeSearch` code has the following signature: `Func<string, IObservable<string>>`.

The important part with this query is the final `Switch` statement. It turns an `IObservable<IObservable<string>>` into a `IObservable<string>` by only returning the results of the latest observable.

The calls to `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` & `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)` ensure that different parts of the observable query happen on the correct threads.

Comment: Thanks for the useful code sample. However, my question asks specifically for an MVVM-friendly solution that avoids Observable.FromEventPattern(). You are using precisely that, combined with event handlers which are not suitable to MVVM.

Comment: @Gigi - You might want to use a hybrid approach then given the answer you've accepted doesn't quite work to only return the latest query results. A pair of long-running queries could come back in any order. My use of `.Switch()` would prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a behavior to get this working. A great example is the [UpdateBindingOnTextChanged  behavior](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/UpdateBindingOnTextChanged) of Catel. It can be used like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchParam, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <catel:UpdateBindingOnTextChanged UpdateDelay="500" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

This will create a 500ms delay between the change and the actual update.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but from what I can understand, it doesn't satisfy the requirement entirely. Part of the instant search functionality is that if a new search is issued while results for the old search haven't yet arrived, the old search is cancelled.