# ReactiveUI 6 instant search (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, reactiveui

I would like to react to user's typing within a text box.

Actually my question is similar to what has already been posted at [Reactive Extensions Instant Search for WPF/MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168500/reactive-extensions-instant-search-for-wpf-mvvm).

Now that we're at the release 6 of ReactiveUI, the previous code is out of date. How can I implement it (with MVVM, i.e. not using events)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compelling example @ http://reactiveui.net/ should help alot. You also want to make sure your xaml TextBox uses the UpdateSourceTrigger

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchQuery, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50" />
```

Code from RXUI copied here:

```
public class SearchViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewHost
{
    public ReactiveList<SearchResults> SearchResults { get; set; }

    private string searchQuery;
    public string SearchQuery {
        get { return searchQuery; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref searchQuery, value); }
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<List<SearchResults>> Search { get; set; }

    public ISearchService SearchService { get; set; }
}
```

and the constructor code

```
// Constructor
public SearchViewModel(ISearchService searchService = null)
{
    SearchService = searchService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<ISearchService>();

    // Here we're describing here, in a *declarative way*, the conditions in
    // which the Search command is enabled.  Now our Command IsEnabled is
    // perfectly efficient, because we're only updating the UI in the scenario
    // when it should change.
    var canSearch = this.WhenAny(x => x.SearchQuery, x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Value));

    // ReactiveCommand has built-in support for background operations and
    // guarantees that this block will only run exactly once at a time, and
    // that the CanExecute will auto-disable and that property IsExecuting will
    // be set according whilst it is running.
    Search = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canSearch, async _ => {
        return await searchService.Search(this.SearchQuery);
    });

    // ReactiveCommands are themselves IObservables, whose value are the results
    // from the async method, guaranteed to arrive on the UI thread. We're going
    // to take the list of search results that the background operation loaded,
    // and them into our SearchResults.
    Search.Subscribe(results => {
        SearchResults.Clear();
        SearchResults.AddRange(results);
    });

    // ThrownExceptions is any exception thrown from the CreateAsyncTask piped
    // to this Observable. Subscribing to this allows you to handle errors on
    // the UI thread.
    Search.ThrownExceptions
        .Subscribe(ex => {
            UserError.Throw("Potential Network Connectivity Error", ex);
        });

    // Whenever the Search query changes, we're going to wait for one second
    // of "dead airtime", then automatically invoke the subscribe command.
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchQuery)
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.Search);
}
```

Comment: Great! I was missing the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged