# Write an Rx “ThrottleUntil” extension method

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am trying to implement search box with auto complete backed by network source.
First, i want limit that request will start only when user pauses writing, this is done with help of Throttle.
Second, i also want limit, that previous request must finish before sending new and value must not be lost, something like ThrottleUntil.
(which must throttle till observable will produce any value)

but, i can't find solution myself.

```cs
IObservable<bool> isLoading;
IObservable<string> inputObservable;
inputObservable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)).ThrottleUntil(isLoading.Where(v=>!v)).Subscribe(/*run loading*/);
```

Here i miss ThrottleUntil extension, or analog.

It's possible to implement it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23209042/402366

Comment: If i understand correctly, that code can run several search requests in same time.

Comment: @A.Kostromtsov - Is there a reason that requests can only be sent one at a time?

Comment: if backend or network lagged, i don't see a reason to send more. Also backend a bit strange, it may answer in wrong order.

Comment: Seems like a terrible UX you are trying to implement. If the user is continuing to type, it seems like it should invalidate previous queries.